# Cassandra Datacenters out of sync - how to diagnose and rebuild?

Tags: cassandra

I've got three cassandra datacenters, with a keyspace that looks like this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE allotments WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'hk1': '3', 'hk2': '3', 'hk3': '3'}  AND durable_writes = false;
```

I installed the latest clusters, HK2 and HK3 recently and had auto_bootstrap set to true (by commenting the line).

I then proceeded to run the rebuild command on all of the nodes in the new datacenters (HK2 and HK3) using the original datacenter (HK1) as the source:

`nodetool rebuild -- hk1`

However, the problem I find myself with is that HK2 seems to be missing data and I am unable to figure out why or fix the problem.

On HK1 (correct data):

```
cqlsh> use allotments;
cqlsh:allotments> select count(*) from freesale_allotments;

 count
-------
 22035

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key

cqlsh:allotments>
```

On HK2 (missing data):

```
cqlsh:allotments> use allotments;  
cqlsh:allotments> select count(*) from freesale_allotments;

 count
-------
 19142

(1 rows)

Warnings :
Aggregation query used without partition key
```

Toubleshooting steps tried so-far:

I tried to rebuild the node again, resetting local data. It would just return within 2-3 seconds:

```
nodetool rebuild -m reset -- hk1
```

I tried running a repair on the keyspace across all nodes, this completed successfully after ~1 hour but the count remains unchanged.

```
nodetool repair allotments -pr
```

I have tried running the scrub command to clean all of the tables of corrupted data, and again - no change.

```
nodetool scrub
```

Can somebody help point me in the right direction to finding out how it has happened, and how i would go about fixing it.

Thanks very much

Martin